# Canvas vs. Panel

Tags: java, canvas, jpanel

If I want to display ellipses and rectangles on a screen, should I use a canvas or a JPanel?

What is the difference? When do I use each?

Comment: use the Swing component.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for the many reasons to use Swing rather than AWT.

Comment: Use `JPanel` for generic tasks. You should only use `Canvas` if you require more control with regards to painting (for instance game titles would use Canvas as they require different buffering strategies, setting FPS and so forth). In a sense, don't agree with many of the answers here; each have their own niche, and Swing runs on top oi the AWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you're using Swing, you should only use Swing components. Mixing Swing and AWT components in the same GUI leads to strange results. So I would use a JPanel, or a raw JComponent.

Answer (score 5):

`Canvas` is an AWT object; `JPanel` is a lightweight Java Swing object.  If you have a Java Swing GUI, I'd strongly recommend using `JPanel`.

Here's a good link on [JPanel](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JPanel.html):

> In the simplest case, you use a `JPanel` exactly the same way as you
>   would a `Panel`. Allocate it, drop components in it, then add the `JPanel`
>   to some `Container`. However, `JPanel` also acts as a replacement for
>   `Canvas` (there is no `JCanvas`)...

Comment: Broken link, I would have liked to read it since this post is 8 years old

Comment: Here is another, different link to the same chapter: [Core Web Programming, Marty Hall, Larry Brown](https://books.google.com/books?id=q45_UDI77PoC&pg=PA585&lpg=PA585&dq=However,+JPanel+also+acts+as+a+replacement+for+Canvas+(there+is+no+JCanvas)...&source=bl&ots=RVHQqXgzW8&sig=ACfU3U1xjQaJJ9DnnnKMJLkf8r0nfEXcag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig4aH5_7PqAhVEUKwKHaBhBAAQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=However%2C%20JPanel%20also%20acts%20as%20a%20replacement%20for%20Canvas%20(there%20is%20no%20JCanvas)...&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a `JLabel` if you want display static images like *icons*.

```
BufferedImage image=
  new BufferedImage(100, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

// draw
g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, rectwidth,rectheight));
g2.fill (new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 50));

JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( image ));
```

Comment: Don't forget to `dispose()` of any `Graphics` instance you explicitly create.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of depends on what you like, but, I would use JFrame, it directly creates a window, and you can draw onto it. Canvas has its advantages, it let's you write one less import, it also separates window stuff from canvas graphics stuff, but it has its the disadvantages of not having access to window. it depends on what you like and need.